# Mocking a service class method giving error

Tags: java, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am new to mockito and junit I dont understand why i am getting error and how to mock this service class method

Please help me to solve this problem. Is there is a need to mock the Pageable and Slice object.
Why after mocking PartnerEventRepository also I am getting error saying

> "Wanted but not invoked: partnerEventRepository.findAll(
>       Cassandra page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: UNSORTED, paging state: null] );"

```
@Service
public class PartnerIndexServiceImpl implements PartnerIndexService {


    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());


    private EventHandler<Event<Entity>, Index> indexEventHandler;
    private PartnerProjectionQueryRepository queryRepository;
    private PartnerEventRepository partnerEventRepository;
    private MessageSource msgSource;


    @Autowired
    private GlobalPartnerProjectionQueryRepository globalPartnerQueryRepo;

    @Autowired
    public PartnerIndexServiceImpl(PartnerProjectionQueryRepository queryRepository,
                              PartnerEventRepository partnerEventRepository,
                              @Qualifier(value = "partnerEventHandler") EventHandler<Event<Entity>, Index> indexEventHandler,
                              MessageSource msgSource) {
        this.queryRepository = queryRepository;
        this.partnerEventRepository = partnerEventRepository;
        this.indexEventHandler = indexEventHandler;
        this.msgSource = msgSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void partnerReIndexing() {
        logger.info("ReIndexing start time : "+new Date());

        List<PartnerEvent> partnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        Pageable pageable = CassandraPageRequest.of(0, 5);
        Slice<PartnerEvent> page = partnerEventRepository.findAll(pageable);
        partnerList.addAll(page.getContent());
        while (page.hasNext()){
            page = partnerEventRepository.findAll(page.nextPageable());
            partnerList.addAll(page.getContent());
        };

        if (partnerList != null) {
            partnerList.parallelStream().forEach(event -> {
                Index index = createPartnerProjection(event);
                indexEventHandler.reIndexEvent(event, index);
            });
        }
        logger.info("ReIndexing end time : "+new Date());
    }


    /*public Slice<PartnerEvent> getPartnersOnBatch(Pageable pageable){
        Slice<PartnerEvent> events = partnerEventRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return events;
    }*/


    private Index createPartnerProjection(PartnerEvent event) {
        PartnerProjectionView.PartnerProjectViewBuilder builder = PartnerProjectionView.builder();

        Partner partner = (Partner) event.getEntity();

        if (partner.getGlobalPartnerRef() != null) {
            String uuid = partner.getGlobalPartnerRef().getUuid();
            if (uuid != null && globalPartnerQueryRepo.findByIdentifier(uuid) == null) {
                throw new BadRequestException("105", "Global Partner with uuid: " + uuid + " doesn't exist");
            }
        }

        builder.uuid(partner.getId());

        List<Attributes> paList = partner.getPartnerAttributes().stream()
                .filter(pa -> pa.getAttributeGroup().equalsIgnoreCase(GROUP_NAME_PARTNER)).map(pa -> pa.getAttributes())
                .findFirst().orElse(null);

        if (paList != null && !paList.isEmpty()) {
            paList.stream().forEach(a -> {
                if ("partnerTaxRegime".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                    builder.partnerTaxRegion(a.getValues().stream()
                            .filter(w -> "*".equals(w.getLang()) || "en".equalsIgnoreCase(w.getLang()))
                            .map(w -> w.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null));
                } else if ("taxOrganisationType".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                    builder.taxOrganisationType(a.getValues().stream()
                            .filter(w -> "*".equals(w.getLang()) || "en".equalsIgnoreCase(w.getLang()))
                            .map(w -> w.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null));
                } else if ("partnerStatus".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                    builder.status(a.getValues().stream()
                            .filter(w -> "*".equals(w.getLang()) || "en".equalsIgnoreCase(w.getLang()))
                            .map(w -> w.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null));
                } else if ("partnername".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                    builder.name(a.getValues().stream()
                            .filter(w -> "*".equals(w.getLang()) || "en".equalsIgnoreCase(w.getLang()))
                            .map(w -> w.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null));
                } else if ("partnernumber".equalsIgnoreCase(a.getName())) {
                    builder.number(a.getValues().stream()
                            .filter(w -> "*".equals(w.getLang()) || "en".equalsIgnoreCase(w.getLang()))
                            .map(w -> w.getValue()).findFirst().orElse(null));
                }
            });
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

mockito

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class PartnerIndexServiceImplTest {

    @MockBean
    private PartnerProjectionQueryRepository queryRepository;
    @MockBean
    private PartnerEventRepository partnerEventRepository;
    @MockBean
    private EventHandler<Event<Entity>, Index> partnerEventHandler;
    @MockBean
    private MessageSource msgSource;

    PartnerIndexService partnerService;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        partnerService = new PartnerIndexServiceImpl(queryRepository, partnerEventRepository, partnerEventHandler,
                msgSource);
    }

    @Test
    public void partnerReIndexing_withPartnerEvent()throws Exception{


        Pageable page = CassandraPageRequest.of(0,5);



        when(partnerEventRepository.findAll(page)).thenReturn(new SliceImpl<>(Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
        verify(partnerEventRepository,times(1)).findAll(page);

    }

}
```

Comment: The detailed error is " Wanted but not invoked:
partnerEventRepository.findAll(
    Cassandra page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: UNSORTED, paging state: null]
);
-> at com.tesco.tps.partner.service.impl.PartnerIndexServiceImplTest.partnerReIndexing_withPartnerEvent(PartnerIndexServiceImplTest.java:83)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

"

Comment: what is the result when you comment out 2nd line? i.e.,      `verify(partnerEventRepository,times(1)).findAll(page);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call your @Test "partnerReIndexing", but I don't see a call to partnerService.partnerReIndexing(). Does this work?

```
@Test
public void partnerReIndexing_withPartnerEvent()throws Exception{
    Pageable page = CassandraPageRequest.of(0,5);
    when(partnerEventRepository.findAll(page)).thenReturn(new SliceImpl<>(Collections.EMPTY_LIST));
    // HERE COMES THE NEW LINE, THAT "ACT" PART OF THE TEST:
    partnerService.partnerReIndexing();
    verify(partnerEventRepository,times(1)).findAll(page);
}
```

Comment: Its working fine now.thanks :) .PartnerService should be mocked or not? If it is a real object then we are directly calling the method with original object.

Comment: And one more thing- how do I call the private method from test as it is private. I am not able to spy the service implementation class

Comment: Depends on what you want to test. My understanding is that you want to test PartnerIndexServiceImpl, and so mocking that object would defy the purpose. Reg. the private methods, there are different points of view. Mine is that you don't test private methods, they are an internal implementation decision. You only test the public/protected methods. If they use private methods to implement the functionality, the test shouldn't care about that. But this is a touchy subject, others will vehemently disagree.